# EXEC and PRINT in a job

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say we have this procedure:

```
create procedure procDoSomeJob 
as  
begin
    print 'Step 1';
    exec procStep1;

    print 'Step 2';
    exec procStep2; -- This step raises a primary key violation

    print 'Step 3';
    exec procStep3;
end;
```

So this procedure calls other procedures, which execute some SQL statements (INSERT, UPDATE).

Let's assume that proc_Step2 raises an error (e.g. primary key violation).

Now, I create a job, and there, this procedure is called like this:

```
exec dbo.procDoSomeJob;
```

Now the interesting part:

After the job has run, in SQL Mgmt Studio, I see in the "Job History" that there was an error and the job "failed".

Also, in the description, I see the output

> **Step 1 Step 2** *(--> WITHOUT "Step 3")*

But when looking into the data, then actually, the procedure procStep3 has been executed !

So why do I not see the output of

```
PRINT 'Step 3';
```

but

```
EXEC procStep3;
```

is actually executed ?

Comment: Inside procStep2 exists proc procStep3 :)

Answer (score 0):

I could replicate this behaviour with a simple example, executed by a SQL agent job just as you describe:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procDoSomeJob 
AS  
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Step 1';

    PRINT 'Step 2';
    RAISERROR('error!', 16,1)

    PRINT 'Step 3';

END;
```

It appears that that once an error occurs, the "message" field in the job history stops capturing any further output from the command, even if another error is raised. If this is documented (it's likely that it is) I haven't found the relevant MSDN entry yet.

If you want to be certain that Step 3 was executed, you'd need to insert a message into a log table rather than relying on the output of `PRINT`.

Comment: thank you; yes, indeed, the PRINT() seems to stop, but the other procedures are still running. Interestingy, if you execute the procedure within a script in SQL Studio, then the you get the full output. Seems that when executed within a job, the behaviour of PRINT() is different.